# I want to implement this kind of collapsing toolbar in my android app

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I am working on an android app and I want to implement this kind of collapsing toolbar where on top the logo of my app is showing and when the user scrolls the search bar stick to the top.

Like this

[[image: this is the first one]

**This is the second one when user scrolls**
[image: this is when user scroll]

Comment: you can check if they published their code on GitHub..

Comment: who published sir?

Comment: The app owners ..

Comment: no brother it is not available there

Comment: That's where i am stucking actually